# Can SSRS 2008 R2 be used to edit SSRS 2008 Reports?

Tags: reporting-services

I am thinking of installing SQL Server 2008 R2 and tools on my box. But it occurred to me this might mean I cannot edit SQL server 2008 reports and use our sql server 2008 report server. 
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the server-side Reporting Services installation will support reports of a lower version level. However, a report will be upgraded if you open it in a higher version level.

So if you want your '2008 reports to keep working on a '2008 Reporting Services installation then do not use '2008 R2 tools to edit them.

Comment: If you open a 2005 report in 2008 or 2008 R2 then it will upgrade the report. If you open a 2008 report in 2008 R2 it won't upgrade it. In the project properties of a 2008 R2 project, you can set the TargetServerVersion property to either SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2008. It doesn't let you target any other version.